# How to populate response data from ajax into select dropdown?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I am getting the response like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id_c] => 7556b3a6-768a-5578-6ebc-5b8a8f758200
            [symptom_c] => Leakage
            [symptom_code_c] => SYM11150
            [defect_c] => ELBOW 3/8 *3/8 PUSHFIT
            [defect_code_c] => LEE88PF2
            [repair_c] => LEE88PF101
            [repair_code_c] => PRTFNTAPE2
            [type_c] => Replaceable
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id_c] => 7ed651a2-77d3-6f82-edb5-5b8cc49a3fed
            [symptom_c] => Leakage Fault
            [symptom_code_c] => SYM11150
            [defect_c] => ELBOW 3/8 *3/8 PUSHFIT
            [defect_code_c] => LEE88PF24575
            [repair_c] => LEE88PF102
            [repair_code_c] => PRTFNTAPE1245
            [type_c] => Replaceable
        )

)
```

How to populate in a select dropdown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. For each object of the response array, adds an option at the end of your select. Not tested but should work

```
$.ajax(
    // your ajax
).done(function(data)
{
    $.each(function(data, index, object)
    {
        $('#yourSelectId').append("<option>" + object.id_c + "</option>");
    }
});
```